# JavaScript object data extraction (JSON Stringify/Parse or without?)

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to figure out if I JSON.Stringify an object like this:

```
{"m_id":"xxx","record":
{"USER":"yyy","PWD","zzz","_createdAt":
11111."_updatedAt":00000},"state":"valid"}
```

and then try to JSON.Parse out only the USER and PWD, not have to just call the object, but go through stringify. how would that work?

thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: you want to reverse the JSON.stringify?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What you say is not true, integers remain integers in a JSON but again, look at the answers below since I think you're trying to do something in an entirely wrong way.


(About the integers:
a = {a:123,b:'123'};
Object {a: 123, b: "123"}
JSON.stringify(a)
"{"a":123,"b":"123"}"
)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there's no way that JSON.stringify() would have produced the string that you showed - that's not valid JSON. @jabbink - I think the OP meant that the property names get quoted when stringified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're talking about stringifying your object. You'd stringify it if you needed to send the data across a network or something, not when you need to manipulate it in JS.

> *...how do I extract the strings in* `{...USER: "aaa", PWD: "zzz"...}`?

Assuming you have a variable referring to the object, something like the following (with or without nice line breaks and indenting to make it readable, and with or without quotes around the property names):

```
var obj = {
    "m_id": "xxx",
    "record": {
        "USER": "yyy",
        "PWD" : "zzz",
        "_createdAt": 11111,
        "_updatedAt": 00000
    },
    "state": "valid"
};
```

Then you can access the properties in the nested `record` object as follows:

```
console.log( obj.record.USER );   // outputs "yyy"
console.log( obj.record.PWD );    // outputs "zzz"
// etc.
```

(Note: in your question you had two typos, a comma that should've been a colon in between `"PWD"` and `"zzz"`, and a dot that should've been a comma in between `11111` and `"_updatedAt"`. There's no way that `JSON.stringify()` would have produced the string that you showed with those mistakes.)

Comment: I guess you're right in that sense, but I was trying to avoid using that.. edited the question above.

Comment: If your requirement is to extract the `"yyy"` and `"zzz"` values then the way I've shown is the correct _and simple_ way to do it. I don't understand why you want to "go through stringify" as per your updated question wording, that doesn't make sense. With an object you can access the properties directly. With a stringified representation you have to write code to parse the string. You can't use `JSON.parse()` to get out individual pieces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the strings `"USER"`, `"PWD"` etc as an array, then use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

If you want to iterate them, just use a normal [`for`-`in` enumeration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the question, but if I think it is what it is then try using

```
var tmp = JSON.parse(string_to_convert)
```

this should suffice to convert your string to a proper Javascript Object

Then you can do

```
for(var index in tmp){
console.log(tmp[index]);
}
```

and this should list all the keys on the first set of properties. If you want to do a nested thing, then use recursion on the properties. Hope this makes sense...